# Gráfico en Matplotlib sale amontonado hacia la izquierda, no muestra la data al editar xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy haciendo un gráfico en Python y sale bien al principio, pero cuando uso la entrada ax.xaxis.set_ticks para seleccionar el salto que peguen los ticks con Numpy, el gráfico se amontona hacia la izquierda y muestra la data desalieneada.

Con np.arange() en otros gráficos pude hacer que las etiquetas sean de 2 en 2, pero en este código no. Cuál es el error?

[image: Este es el gráfico que resulta de incluir la sentencia de ax.xaxis.set_ticks con un np.arange, obviamente no ideal para mostrar la data]

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Roderick\Downloads\series-091119.csv', skiprows=8, header=None)

dates = df[0].values.tolist()
inflation = df[1].values.tolist()

yrs = dates[0:30]
inf = inflation[0:30]

xticks = np.arange(1989,2019,2)

fmt = ticker.PercentFormatter()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.title('Inflation 1989-2018', color='k', size='13', style='italic', ha='left')
ax.plot(yrs, inf, color='b', marker='.', linewidth='1', label='UK Inflation')

ax.xaxis.set_ticks(xticks, minor=False)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(yrs, minor=True)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)

ax.grid(which='major', color='lightgrey', linestyle='--')
ax.grid(which='minor', color='grey', linestyle=':')

plt.show()
```

Comment: comparte el .csv

Comment: Puede descargarse de este link https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/inflationandpriceindices/timeseries/l55o/mm23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que un posible origen del problema que tienes es que estás leyendo un archivo csv que contiene más filas de datos que los que quieres representar en tu gráfico. Te recomiendo limpiar los datos de tu archivo csv y quedarte solo con las dos columnas que quieres graficar (`dates`, `inflation`).

Una vez hecho esto, el código que tienes funciona correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker


df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\XXXXXXXXXX\Downloads\series-081119.csv', skiprows=1, header=None)

dates = df[0].values.tolist()
inflation = df[1].values.tolist()

yrs = dates[0:30]
inf = inflation[0:30]

xticks = np.arange(1989,2019,2)

# fmt = ticker.PercentFormatter()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.title('Inflation 1989-2018', color='k', size='13', style='italic', ha='left')
ax.plot(yrs, inf, color='b', marker='.', linewidth='1', label='UK Inflation')

ax.xaxis.set_ticks(xticks, minor=False)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(yrs, minor=True)

# ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.PercentFormatter())

ax.grid(which='major', color='lightgrey', linestyle='--')
ax.grid(which='minor', color='grey', linestyle=':')

plt.show()
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con limpiar el .csv? Además del índice, tiene solo dos columnas [0] y [1] sin header, y las filas ya filtro las primeras 8 que incluyen datos al no llamarlas y las 30 primeras que contienen los datos relevantes al crear las variables con values.tolist(). Puedes compartir foto del código o de cómo modificaste el .csv? Muchas gracias.

Comment: El archivo csv descargable del link que has compartido tiene 530 filas de datos, y a no ser que me equivoque los datos que entiendo necesitas están entre las filas 9 y 38. Con limpiar me refiero a que edites el archivo csv para para quedarte solo con las variables correspondientes a años e inflación. El código que he utilizado es el mismo que el tuyo.